# what are the advantages of using javacv than opencv?

Tags: opencv, javacv

I'am developing an eye gaze estimation desktop application for my final year project. I wanted to know what are the main advantages of using javaCV instead of OpenCV ?

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV is a very good Computer visio library. It has C, C++ and Python API. JavaCV is Wrapper of OpenCV using java.

Based on your application you can use native C API using Android NDK. If you are focus on Java then you can use JavaCV.

Also you can have a look at [this](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html) and some [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

`JavaCV` is just a non-official `Java` version of `OpenCV`.

That said, use `JavaCV` if you are going to develop in `Java`, and use `OpenCV` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tutorial for javacv. Sometimes you can't find the curresponding java implementation for Opencv's class(c++ code).Don't get frustrated.Just try to implement it in your own way and open source it.So, others can use it.Be a leader.All the best.